# Drag and drop with Web storage HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, web-storage

I wanted to know how to bind a drag and drop of div with `Web storage`.

*I followed this tutorial:*
[Tutorial Drag and Drop (div)](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)

The tutorial works but I would like to bind it to Web storage.
I don't know how to make to work.

Thank you in advance for your answers.